# Send text and binary via websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there any way to send text and binary in one request via websocket? For example: file name (text) and file content (binary)

I can send them as string like:

```
JSON.stringify({filename: "test.dat", filecontent: data});
```

But it is a lot slower than sending only file content as binary (arraybuffer).

Comment: Maybe you want to look at a different data interchange format that has native support for binary data, such as MsgPack.

Comment: @mpen - webSocket supports binary data.

Comment: @jfriend00 Right.. I'm saying instead of using `JSON.stringify` use `msgpack.encode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that binary is just encoded data. This is less a JavaScript question and more an encoding question. Here's how I would do it.

Set aside 32 bits (representing one integer) at the beginning of your request to specify the bit length of `test.dat`. Then combine this with your two data sources. Your payload will look like this:

> TEXT_LENGTH + TEST.DAT AS BINARY + FILECONTENT AS BINARY

Then get back the data as an array buffer. Use

```
textLengthBits = parseInt(arrBuffer.slice(0,32), 2);
```

To get the length of the text. Then slice again,

```
textBits = arrBuffer.slice(32, 32 + textLengthBits)
```

To get the text. The remaining bits are your file.

```
fileBits = arrBuffer.slice(32 + textLengthBits);
```